# Why am I getting this error in header file "expected initializer before 'vector'"

Tags: c++

I get this error when I am compiling the project with:

**g++  -I./src -MMD -MP -std=c++11   -c -o src/scape.o src/scape.cpp**

One of the files that is included in scape.cpp is tools.hpp and it is in this file that I get the error:

**src/tools.hpp:4:2: error: expected initializer before ‘vector’**

Here follows the tools.hpp code:

```
#ifndef TOOLSHPP
    #define TOOLSHPP

    vector<int> decToBinary (unsigned long long int , int );
    int countFreq (string , string);
    vector<string> split_string (string ); 
    void remove_if_in_list (vector<int>& , vector<int> );
    vector<int> union_of_vectors (vector<int>, vector<int>); 
    void remove_file (string );
    void call_delay();

#endif
```

So I'm expetcing that the error is due to something I am missing before the 'vector' but I really don't see what is it?

**EDITED**

After trying some ideas I also figured out that the error is not only related to the 'vector'. If I change lines in the above code resulting in the code bellow, the error changes to:

*src/tools.hpp:7:2: error: expected initializer before ‘int’*

```
#ifndef TOOLSHPP
    #define TOOLSHPP

    #include <string>
    #include <vector>

    int countFreq (std::string, std::string);
    std::vector<int> decToBinary (unsigned long long int, int);
    std::vector<std::string> split_string (std::string); 
    void remove_if_in_list (std::vector<int>&, std::vector<int>);
    std::vector<int> union_of_vectors (std::vector<int>, std::vector<int>); 
    void remove_file (std::string);
    void call_delay();

#endif
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Try `#include <vector>` and then change `vector<int>` to `std::vector<int>`

Comment: So after I did exaclty what you said I get: error: expected initializer before ‘std’

Comment: the error is in scape.cpp or one of the files included just before tools.hpp is included.

Comment: The error I mentioned in the questions is in 'tools.hpp' which is the header of tools.cpp, which is included by scape.cpp.

Comment: The error in the "edit" is probably due to a mistake in whatever file did `#include "tools.hpp"`, such as a missing semicolon. Although you also use `vector` without `std::` multiple times

Comment: @M.M got it. It was a chain of header files and one of them had a missing semicolon. And, as expected, the error has pointing to the next line which was in another file and it was making me look at the wrong place for the error. Thanks to this hint I found the source of error. How should I proceed to make this solution clearer to the ones that will come to this question in the future?

Comment: @elrhod You would have to include the file with the missing semicolon (or crucial part of that file) in the question - but such a question would probably be closed as a "typo" question and closed rather quickly, so perhaps you can just remove it.

Comment: Even though the error was a typo, I decided to leave the question here as the way the error was presented it can make it hard to find. I will present the solution including the file with the missing semicolon as you suggested. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The erros was actually in another file "pos_processing.hpp" (below):

```
#ifndef POSPROCESSINGHPP
    #define POSPROCESSINGHPP

    #include "types.hpp"

    void update_report (MyGraphType, vector<int> , int , int , map<int,vector<errorProbabilityType>>& );
    void generate_report (string , string , map< int, vector<errorProbabilityType> > )

#endif
```

There is a missing semicolon in the last function declaration.
This header file was included together with other headers, as presented bellow.

```
#include "scape.hpp"
#include "exprtk.hpp"
#include "types.hpp"
#include "debug.hpp"
#include "pre_processing.hpp"
#include "pos_processing.hpp"
#include "tools.hpp"
#include "scape_utils.hpp"
```

As the error is a missing semicolon in the last line of the file, the compiler understands that the next line (which is in the next include file) is part of the previous one, and ends up indicating the error in the next line, which is in the "tools.hpp" file. That is why the error was in one file but was being indicated at the other.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your `tools.hpp` file does not use `#include <vector>` and `std` namespace.

Comment: Thanks for the help. It didn't work. I added more info in the question to help.